# How do I find the standing of a journal or conference for an academic CV?

Tags: phd, publications, cv

I'm writing an academic CV for a PhD application and they have asked for the standing of journals or conferences of published articles.

> **Research publications**
>
> Include articles published or accepted for publication (with the three most significant marked with an asterisk).  Please specify the publication details, your contribution as an author to multi-authored publications, plus the standing of the journal or conference.

I'm really not sure what they are looking for or how to express this. Is it the impact factor of the journal? And what about conference proceedings which don't have impact factors?

Comment: What country and field is this in? The Australian Research Council puts out a [list](http://www.arc.gov.au/era/era_2010/archive/era_journal_list.htm) of journal and conference rankings, but I'm not sure any other institutions outside of that country care.

Comment: @BillBarth It is indeed for an Australian university but it is not for any specific field as it is listed on the [Graduate School's website](http://www.uq.edu.au/grad-school/academic-cv).

Comment: For conferences you could give the number of accepted and rejected papers. Though I am not sure if all conferences distribute that data. This also assumes that conference papers are peer reviewed in your field.

Comment: I sent an email to the university to try and get some clarification. No reply yet. I'll update once they get back to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems it isn't actually that important. I sent them an email to clarify and they replied:

> Don’t worry too much about the standing of the journal or conference, as long as you list any publications and conferences that you have.

Answer (score 3):

For applications to Australian universities, I suspect they want the ranking from the [Ranked Outlets list](http://www.arc.gov.au/era/era_2010/archive/era_journal_list.htm) produced by the Australian Research Council.

Comment: Thanks for the info though the lists aren't available for download anymore. At least they aren't available without using the [wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20120118091323/http://www.arc.gov.au/era/era_2010/archive/era_journal_list.htm). Unfortunately they don't list the particular conferences I'm looking for, or any conferences in the particular field (life cycle assessment).

Answer (score 1):

Use something that the selection committee can easily verify. I would use [Google Scholar Metrics](http://scholar.google.co.in/citations?view_op=top_venues&hl=en) and provide the h5-index and h5-median values. The good thing about Google Scholar is that it also automatically generates these numbers for most major conferences. Be sure to mention the following Google disclaimer in the footnote:

*"Dates and citation counts are estimated and are determined automatically by a computer program."*

Comment: Thanks for the info I didn't realise that existed.　But I guess it's actually not that different to journal impact factors which cannot really be compared between fields and is almost useless in multi-disciplinary fields such as for myself. I quite agree with [this answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/15924/19543) regarding including impact factors on you CV.